# Just upload changed files to ESP32 with PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, esp32, micropython

I started using PyCharm with the Micropython plugin to programm a ESP32.
Since my project has multiple files it takes ages to upload everything every time I do a change to the code.
Is there any option to just update the changed files so the upload works much faster?